# Auto answer “Y” to simple CLI command with DOS command

Tags: windows, automation, command-line

I need to automate the following command that runs on win xp (from CMD window )

```
     D:\Documents and Settings\muser>  erase_disk.exe
```

after 10 minutes I get the question:
                                          are you sure to erase disk(y/n)

Is it possible by using dos xp commands to send “y” character to command line? so I will not need to wait and type “y”

- I have tried the following but its not works

  ```
         echo y| erase_disk.exe
  ```

other different example

```
     D:\Documents and Settings\muser>  scan_virus_on_my_email.exe
```

after 1 hour I get:

```
                                       proccess ended to you want to exit (y/n)
```

Comment: The question seems valid, but thought I might suggest; lots of Linux programs I know of have an option to disable confirmations so they can be automated. I don't know if yours does. (entering "erase_disk.exe /h" *might* give you more information)

Comment: yes but this is only example , what I want is to know if we can to auto CLI command in one line  , I try many options to lunch the "y" argument in to the command line so it will be automate the proccess , but as you see I not succeed

Comment: You might want to check out the unix [yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)) command (possibly getting the source and compiling it for dos).

Comment: I am not sure if we can to it ( yes is linux/unix command ) - how to compile it to WIN ENV?

Comment: @maihabunash you get a complier and compile the code.  One version of it on [google code](https://code.google.com/p/cshell/source/browse/trunk/src/commands/yes.c).  It should be trivial to write a similar program in a scripting language present on the machine if you don't have a compiler.

Comment: Good gravy, if you don't want the options, the entire source for `yes` is `int main() { while ( 1 ) { printf("y\n"); } }`.

Comment: thx MichaelT - the sad news is that I only know linux , and not have experience with that

Comment: Your problem likely originates from the fact that the prompt is shown after a delay. Perhaps a VBScript that uses [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) might be able to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a really long time since I've done this, but in the past to automate some things we had a Y in a text file, like y.txt, and then in our batch files had statements like:

```
erase_disk < y.txt
```

Comment: That do work on Unix/Linux, but remember to insert an <kbd>ENTER</kbd> at the end of the line

Comment: how ? , if I put the "y" in y.txt how to edit the enter in the y.txt file?

Comment: @maihabunash just hit enter after the "y". I used that technique once but I just needed the ENTER, so I created a file with just a new line character.

Comment: yes - I did it but still I get the question - are you sure to erase disk(y/n)

Comment: I dont sure but maybe need to create soome .bat file that send the "y" string to CLI - am I right?